# alexusmai laravel-file-manager s3 bucket image have view option but other documents like pdf excel have no view option

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, amazon-s3, file-manager

when I right click on image its have view,delete,properties,rename,select option..but click on pdf or excel no view option..this image showing from s3 bucket

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaPQF.png)

I need preview of pdf excel and all other documents. Now only image preview